# Ruby while loop keeps repeating regardless of input

Tags: ruby, loops, until-loop

I wrote a simple guess the number game. But it keeps looping even when I input the correct number. Please help, thanks!

```
puts "Pick a number between 0 - 1000."
user_guess = gets.chomp.to_i

my_num = rand(831)
guess_count = 0

until user_guess == my_num do
  if user_guess == my_num
    guess_count += 1
    puts "you got it!"
  elsif  user_guess <= 830
    guess_count += 1
    puts "higher"
  else user_guess >= 1000
    guess_count += 1
    puts "lower"
  end 
end

puts "You guessed my number in #{guess_count} attempts. Not bad"
```

Answer (score 1):

The part of the code that asks for a number from the user is outside the loop, so it will not repeat after the answer is checked. If you want to ask the user to guess again when their guess is wrong, that code needs to be inside the loop.

```
my_num = rand(831)
guess_count = 0
keep_going = true


while keep_going do
  puts "Pick a number between 0 - 1000."
  user_guess = gets.chomp.to_i
  if user_guess == my_num
    guess_count += 1
    puts "you got it!"
    keep_going = false
  elsif  user_guess <= 830
    guess_count += 1
    puts "higher"
  else user_guess >= 1000
    guess_count += 1
    puts "lower"
  end 
end


puts "You guessed my number in #{guess_count} attempts. Not bad"
```

This code still has some bugs in it that stops the game from working correctly though, see if you can spot what they are.

Comment: such a newb mistake. thank you for the edit and the debugging practice.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tobias has answered your question I would like to take some time to suggest how you might make your code more Ruby-like.

Firstly, while you could use a `while` or `until` loop, I suggest you rely mainly on the method [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) for most loops you will write. This simply causes looping to continue within `loop`'s block until the keyword `break` is encountered<sup>1</sup>. It is much like `while true` or `until false` (commonly used in some languages) but I think it reads better. More importantly, the use of `loop` protects computations within its block from prying eyes. (See the section *Other considerations* below for an example of this point.)

You can also exit `loop`'s block by executing `return` or `exit`, but normally you will use `break`.

My second main suggestion is that for this type of problem you use a `case statement` rather than an `if/elsif/else/end` construct. Let's first do that using ranges.

**Use a case statement with ranges**

```
my_num = rand(831)
guess_count = 0

loop do
  print "Pick a number between 0 and 830: "
  guess_count += 1
  case gets.chomp.to_i
  when my_num
    puts "you got it!"
    break
  when 0..my_num-1
    puts "higher"
  else
    puts "lower"
  end
end
```

There are a few things to note here.

- I used `print` rather than `puts` so the user will enter their response on on the same line as the prompt.
- `guess_count` is incremented regardless of the user's response so that can be done before the case statement is executed.
- there is no need to assign the user's response (`gets.chomp.to_i`) to a variable.
- case statements compare values with the appropriate *case equality method* `===`.

With regard to the last point, here we are comparing an integer (`gets.chomp.to_i`) with another integer (`my_num`) and with a range `(0..my_num-1)`. In the first instance, `Integer#===` is used, which is equivalent to `Integer#==`. For ranges the method [Range#===](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) is used.

Suppose, for example, that `my_num = 100` and `gets.chomp.to_i #=> 50` The case statement then reads as follows.

```
case 50
when 100
  puts "you got it!"
  break
when 0..99
  puts "higher"
else
  puts "lower"
end
```

Here we find that `100 == 50 #=> false` and `(0..99) === 50 #=> true`, so `puts "higher"` is displayed. `(0..99) === 50` returns `true` because the integer (on the right of `===`) is *covered* by the range (on the left). That is not the same as `50 === (0..90)`, which loosely reads, "`(0..99)` is a *member* of `50`", so `false` is returned.

Here are a couple more examples of how case statements can be used to advantage because of their reliance on the triple equality method.

```
case obj
when Integer
  obj + 10
when String
  obj.upcase
when Array
  obj.reverse
...
end
```

```
case str
when /\A#/
  puts "A comment"
when /\blaunch missiles\b/
  big_red_button.push
...
end
```

**Use a case statement with the *spaceship operator* `<=>`**

The spaceship operator is used by Ruby's [Array#sort](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) and [Enumerable#sort](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) methods, but has other uses, as in case statements. Here we can use [Integer#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) to compare two integers.

```
my_num = rand(831)
guess_count = 0

loop do
  print "Pick a number between 0 and 830: "
  case gets.chomp.to_i <=> my_num
  when 0
    puts "you got it!"
    break
  when -1         
    puts "higher"
  else # 1
    puts "lower"
  end
end
```

In other applications the spaceship operator might be used to compare strings ([String#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)), arrays ([Array#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)), `Date` objects ([Date#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)) and so on.

**Use a hash**

Hashes can often be used as an alternative to `case statements`. Here we could write the following.

```
response = { -1=>"higher", 0=>"you got it!", 1=>"lower" }
my_num = rand(831)
guess_count = 0

loop do
  print "Pick a number between 0 and 830: "
  guess = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts response[guess <=> my_num]
  break if guess == my_num
end
```

Here we need the value of `gets.chomp.to_i` twice, so I've saved it to a variable.

**Other considerations**

Suppose we write the following:

```
i = 0
while i < 5
  i += 1
  j = i
end
j #=> 5
```

`j` following the loop is found to equal `5`.

If we instead use `loop`:

```
i = 0
loop do
  i += 1
  j = i
  break if i == 5
end
j #=> NameError (undefined local variable or method 'j')
```

Although `while` and `loop` both have access to `i`, but `loop` confines the values of local variables created in its block to the block. That's because blocks create a new *scope*, which is good coding practice. `while` and `until` do not use blocks. We generally don't want code following the loop to have access to local variables created within the loop, which is one reason for favouring `loop` over `while` and `until`.

Lastly, the keyword `break` can also be used with an argument whose value is returned by `loop`. For example:

```
def m
  i = 0
  loop do
    i += 1
    break 5*i if i == 10
  end
end

m #=> 50
```

or

```
i = 0
n = loop do
  i += 1
  break 5*i if i == 10
end
n #=> 50
```

<sup>1. If you examine the doc for `Kernel#loop` you will see that executing `break` from within `loop`'s block is equivalent to raising a `StopIteration` exception.</sup>